# "google api is already presented"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

[Google map "loading" and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUJaO.png)

[MapScreen file in react app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeBrO.png)

[Repository](https://github.com/ojc011/ecommercebiz)

```
const libs = ['places'];
```

```
 return (
    <div className="full-box">
      <LoadScript libraries={libs} googleMapsApiKey={googleApiKey}>
        <GoogleMap
          id="smaple-map"
          mapContainerStyle={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
          center={center}
          zoom={15}
          onLoad={onLoad}
          onIdle={onIdle}
        >
          <StandaloneSearchBox
            onLoad={onLoadPlaces}
            onPlacesChanged={onPlacesChanged}
          >
            <div className="map-input-box">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your address"></input>
              <Button type="button" onClick={onConfirm}>
                Confirm
              </Button>
            </div>
          </StandaloneSearchBox>
          <Marker position={location} onLoad={onMarkerLoad}></Marker>
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>
    </div>
  );
```

I am getting this error when trying to implement google maps api into my ecommerce application. I have read other threads saying I can only have one , however, I do only have one loadscript tag on this entire application so that did not solve the issue for me. Hopefully I am not glossing over something silly but I've been stuck on this error for a few days now trying to find a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Error google api is alread present is occurring due to where you are instantiating the LoadScript component.

You will need to move LoadScript to a parent component that will not rerender. The best place will be close to the root of your tree.

Please check out [this issue](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/issues/70) for more clarity.